# stored procedure variable

Tags: mysql

I would like to set up a query in a stored procedure like:

```
select * from table where xx between '2010' and '2011'
```

To use some variable (time) instead of the static timestamp.  However once I set up the variable and query like

`"select * from table where xx between time and time"`   or

```
"select * from table where xx between 'time' and 'time'",
```

it doesn't work, could you help me

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier if we had real code, but, based on what you've provided, I'd say:

1. "time" is a function name in mysql.  While it's not listed as a reserved word, it would still scare me to use it as such.
2. I don't believe that "between" can be parameterized with variables.  Not 100% on this, though.
3. I'd try "where my_time > start_time and my_time < end_time"

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx for the response, i also tried like this:  i set up variable time1 and time2="2011-1-1 11:00:00", and then i query like: between (select time1) and (select time2);  it works